# C++/CLI Generic Static Class

Tags: c#, generics, c++-cli

I've been trying to convert some C# code to C++/CLI code (for some performance reasons, as well as avoiding a bunch of interop issues), however I've hit a wall. Admittedly, my C++/CLI knowledge is lacking (at the absolute best).

Trying to convert a generic static class, that we used for size caching, is proving to be a major headache.

The C# class is as follows;

```
public static class SizeCache<T>
{
    public static int Size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
}
```

And the C++/CLI wrapper (as far as I've gotten) is the following;

```
    generic <typename T>
public ref class SizeCache abstract sealed
{
private:
    static SizeCache()
    {
        Size = Marshal::SizeOf(T::typeid);
    }

public:
    static int Size;
};
```

Everything seems to compile fine, however, when I access it via;

```
int size = SizeCache<T>::Size;
```

I get compiler errors.

> error C2039: 'Size' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
>
> error C2065: 'Size' : undeclared identifier

Unfortunately, I can't see what I'm doing wrong in this case.

The reason for the class in the first place, is to avoid some issues with the Marshaler (specifically when dealing with generic structure types), and avoid the performance hit incurred by constantly calling SizeOf on the same basic types.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you are quoting error messages that are half-way down the error list.  You should have gotten a diagnostic for the unknown SizeCache identifier first, the only conceivable way the compiler could think that Size is in the global namespace.  Start at the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Note that even though the code is written in C++/CLI the call to Marshal::SizeOf is still a managed call. I don't expect any performance improvement even if you successfully compile the code.

Did you try caching the results in a hashtable instaed of resorting to C++/CLI?

I just tested your code and it works perfectly (just copy/paste the code below):

```
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

  generic <typename T>
public ref class SizeCache abstract sealed
{
private:
    static SizeCache()
    {
        Size = Marshal::SizeOf(T::typeid);
    }

public:
    static int Size;
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    double dsize = SizeCache<double>::Size;
    int size = SizeCache<int>::Size;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The conversion to C++/CLI isn't just for this specific case. It's mostly for other, larger, portions of the library. Storing it in a Hashtable (or Dictionary, or any other variant) basically nullifies the reason for having a static-generic class. This lets me do all my reflection work for the specific type once, and incur no lookup penalty when the type is used again later.